# Adding loops to a formula and displaying only the values of the formula computation

Tags: excel, vba, do-loops

I have two issues that I would appreciate a lot of help on:

1. I have VBA linked to a button which computes values on some cells based on the inputted parameters. I am still a basic user however and could not get it to loop. The intention is for the VBA to continue to calculate until the value in a given cell zero.
2. Is it possible to have VBA to compute input values only into the cell without inputting the corresponding formula? See a snippet of the code below:

   Sub Formular1()
       ' Formular1

   ```
   Range("H17").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUNDDOWN((RC[-1]-RC[-2])/30,0)"
   ActiveCell.Select

   ' Formular2 Macro
   Range("I17").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]/RC[-1]"
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

   ' Formular 3
   Range("J17").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R4C9"
   Range("J20").Select

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write the formula into the cell and immediately revert the formula to its returned value or calculate the value and write it into the cell directly.

```
dim nr as long
'option 1
with activesheet
    nr = .cells(rows.count, "H").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row
    .cells(nr, "H").formula = "=TRUNC((G" & nr & "-F" & nr & ")/30)"
    .cells(nr, "I").formula = "=G" & nr & "/F" & nr
    .cells(nr, "J").formula = "=I4"
    with .cells(nr, "H").resize(1, 3)
        .value = .value
    end with
end with

'option 2
with activesheet
    nr = .cells(rows.count, "H").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row
    .cells(nr, "H") = int((.cells(nr, "D").value - .cells(nr, "H").value) / 30)
    .cells(nr, "I") = cdbl(.cells(nr, "G").value / .cells(nr, "F").value)
    .cells(nr, "J") = .cells(4, "I").value
end with
```

There you have examples of each method. I did simplify your first formula a bit by using the [TRUNC function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRUNC-function-8B86A64C-3127-43DB-BA14-AA5CEB292721) in place of the [ROUNDDOWN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDDOWN-function-2EC94C73-241F-4B01-8C6F-17E6D7968F53) but they both perform the same operation in this case.

I am a little concerned that you seem to be writing these formula/values into a new row but you are referencing other cells in the same row. I would have to suppose that these other cells have been populated with formulas or values first.

Comment: I just updated and it worked like magic. Thank you. However, i want to make some changes and i don't want to destroy what you have done. I would like to change the relative cell selection at the beginning of the code to absolute and i would like to add a loop. Firstly, I want the computations to always start from row 19 and to end on the row where column G does not have any value. Thanks again. Could you please add comments to your codes so that i can at least learn and improve?

Answer (score -2):

not exactly sure what you are trying to do. but

obviously I am not using your range exactly because you did not provide enough information about what you want to do.

if you want to go through a range of cells and convert formulas into values, it would be something like this.

```
for each rcell in worksheet("myworksheet").Range("A1:A15").Cells
if rcell.value = "0" then
exit sub
else
rcell.value = rcell.value
end if
next rcell
```

By the way, a friend told me about this site he used. he said they provide a few free training videos on basic excel formulas no vba yet, but that he used them to create a macro for him and it was a very reasonable cost.

http://www.excelformulashelp.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think jeeped has done justice already to the question. But could you please proffer a solution to loop question?